# RxJs 5 periodic polling with out of order refreshing

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following code (httpObservable completes on first emission) which polls service with fixed "dead time":

```
return serviceObservable.expand(() => Observable.timer(period).concatMap(() => serviceObservable));
```

How can I make the timer "resettable" by using `Subject` which emits every time the timer should be resetted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return serviceObservable
    .expand(() => Observable
        .timer(period)
        .race(subject.take(1))
        .concatMap(() => serviceObservable));
```